# Entangled spin anti-correlations observed relative to what?

Tags: reference-frames, quantum-spin, quantum-entanglement, observers

Alice and Bob work in a large room. In the middle of the room,
they have a device that generates spin-entangled particle pairs;
one member of each pair goes to Alice’s bench, the other one, to Bob’s.
The particles travel parallel to the floor,
and the angle from one particle, to the generator, to the other particle, is 180º.
Alice and Bob both measure spin in the vertical direction, and yes, they confirm
that whenever Alice measures “up”, Bob measures “down” and vice-versa.

Now they set the generator so that the particles it sends out,
still move parallel to the floor, but make an angle of 120º.
They move their benches so that they can still intercept and measure.
It is still the case that the vertical spin measurements anti-correlate perfectly.

Next, they install the particle generator on a geo-stationary satellite,
and station that over the equator. Alice’s instruments get lofted onto a balloon
over the North Pole, and Bob’s instruments, over the South Pole.
The generator still manages to send spin-entangled particles to both.

Question: will Alice and Bob’s spin measurements still be anti-correlated,
or will they be exactly correlated? In other words, does the difference,
or the consistency, between what Alice calls “up” and what Bob calls “up”
have to do with the direction of gravity, or,
with the direction from the researcher to some distant astronomical object?

Comment: It’s the latter; we define “up” in a single inertial frame.

Comment: Thank you! The inertial frame would be that of the particle generator, yes?

Comment: It doesn't actually matter which one you use. The spins will always be opposite. In one frame, that might mean that if you measure "down" I measure "up". But in a tilted frame, that might mean that if you measure "left" I measure "right".

Comment: @knzhou This is wrong in most cases. Photons sent through a fibre end up with a rotated polarization (which drifts), spins will precess if they travel through a magnetic field. Maybe if you have a source of entangled neutrinos.

Comment: @TomTelos Unless you specify more details (*what* entangled particles, *how* do you produce them, *how* do you send them), this is impossible to answer. In any case, the magic about entanglement is ***not*** the perfect anticorrelation!

Comment: ...the magic about entanglement is not the perfect anticorrelation?
Would you please clarify that?